# How to post arrays from PHP file into a table using JQuery $.getJSON?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to output an array to a table, based on a user entered variable called `firstname`. If two arrays have the same `firstname` value the table should display both arrays. Currently, only the first array is being displayed in the table. I have included my current code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var url = "data.php";

    $('#getJSON').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        url = url + "?firstname=" + firstname;

        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                tr = $("<tr/>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json.data[0].id + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json.data[0].title + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json.data[0].firstname + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP script:

```
if ($firstname === "Emma")
    $arr[] = array('id'=> "1", 'title'=> "Miss", 'firstname'=> "Emma", 'surname'=>"Brown");
else if ($firstname === "Emma")
        $arr[] = array('id'=> "2", 'title'=> "Mrs", 'firstname'=> "Emma", 'surname'=>"Green");
else
        $arr[] = array('id'=> "Unknown", 'title'=> "Unknown", 'firstname'=> "Unknown", 'surname'=> "Unknown");

echo '{"firstname":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

I would like it to output like so:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: everytime you loop your overwriting `tr` `tr = $("<tr/>");`

Comment: @atoms thats fine as `tr` gets appended at the end of each iteration

Comment: @Emma can you give us an example of both the JSON you're retrieving and also the output you expect. I don't understand what you mean by 'if the firstnames match it should display both arrays'. You also probably want to change `[0]` to `[i]`

Comment: And since you've tagged PHP here can you show us the script which generates the JSON?

Comment: your code is fine try to `console.log(url);` before the `for` loop to check if you are getting the expected results.. I think your php script is returnig only the first match.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have added in the arrays in my PHP file and an image of the expected output. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: In the PHP code you posted the `else if ($firstname === "Emma")` condition would never be called since the first condition is exactly the same and you are overwriting the first index of `$arr` every time. Please change `$arr[0]` to `$arr[]`.

Comment: You have added two same conditions separately. So, once the condition is met, the second one will be last one to take effect and fetches the data. Therefore, the Emma array with the surname Green will be the output to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

First one is the use of the if clause. Since you are using `if elseif` you cannot put the same condition in both `if` and `elseif`.The `else if` means if previous condition is false then check another condition. In this case the elseif will never be executed since the first condition is true.

Second you are always storing data in the same index of your results array so you will overwrite your data and always get one element in this array.

```
$id=1;
$arr=array();

if ($firstname === "Emma"){
    $arr[] = array('id'=> $id++, 'title'=> "Miss", 'firstname'=> "Emma", 'surname'=>"Brown");
    $arr[] = array('id'=> $id++, 'title'=> "Mrs", 'firstname'=> "Emma", 'surname'=>"Green");
 }

 else if($firstname === "NotEmma")
     $arr[] = array('id'=> $id++, 'title'=> "Miss", 'firstname'=> "NotEmma", 'surname'=>"xx");

 else
        $arr[] = array('id'=> "Unknown", 'title'=> "Unknown", 'firstname'=> "Unknown", 'surname'=> "Unknown");

echo '{"firstname":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

Comment: Thank you Amani! PHP isn't my strong point at all, but this is working perfectly. :)

Comment: you are welcome, it's not complicated you have only to understand the logic behind what you are trying to do first then translate it to code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    tr += "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>" + json.data[i].id += "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + json.data[i].title += "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + json.data[i].firstname += "</td>";
    tr += "</tr>";

}

$('table').html(tr);
```

Comment: While this may perform better, it's logically the same as what the OP has now, so how will this be of any benefit? Not my downvote, FYI

Comment: Works for me, only other reason I could think of is a broken response. So if this wouldn't work OP should check his response.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.